# Sphinx sql_query with variables

Tags: mysql, sql, sphinx

Is it possibel to use variables in the Sphinx main SQL query (in sphinx.conf)? 
Like this:

```
sql_query = SELECT \
               id, user_id, title \
            FROM \
                user_has_book \
            WHERE user_id = $userid;
```

Or do I have to load all the books and then filter by user_id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load all books then filter. Put user_id as attribute.

The sql_query is run once to build the index, once built no sql queries are run by indexer or searchd.